# Examples of sub-bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

I was wondering if anyone has any examples of sub-bundles of a bundle. Intuitively, I think that a Möbius strip is a sub-bundle of a torus since you can think of a torus as a circle that you attach discs to, while a Möbius strip is a circle that you attach lines to. The lines can be picked so that they are submanifolds of the discs. Am I correct?

Comment: What's the difference between a Mobius strip and a cylinder then?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a subbundle?

Comment: Yes. The definition I have is that $(E',\pi',M')$ is a subbundle of $(E,\pi,M)$ if $E'$ is a submanifold of $E$, $M'$ is a submanifold of $M$ and $\pi'$ is $\pi$ restricted to $E'$.

Comment: @Pinapple Oh, where did you find it?

Comment: @MoisheKohan https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGEV0Wk0eIk&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&index=6&ab_channel=FredericSchuller at 46:10.

Comment: My suggestion is not to rely upon Youtube videos for learning serious math. Books and online written material in the form of lecture notes will be much more reliable.